# Xcode error: qualified member access refers to a member in the global namespace

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
{
...
    std::ofstream output_data;
    output_data.open("output.dat");
    output_data << "pi" >>
    output_data.::close("output.dat");
}
```

Error occurs at 'output_data.::close("output.dat");' saying "Qualified member access refers to member in the global namespace", does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Stop using the invalid syntax? Why do you think you need `::` there?

Comment: There's also a stray ">>" and a missing semicolon in `output_data << "pi" >>`. You should probably study some more about what the symbols *mean* – programming languages are very picky about punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get rid of the `::` in `output_data.::close("output.dat");` and secondly [`std::ofstream::close`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) doesn't take any parameters.  It should just be

```
output_data.close();
```

Also since a `ofstream` object will close itself when it goes out of scope in this case there is no reason to call close.  You can just let it drop out of scope and it will take case of itself.